# How to flip only the image horizontally not canvs?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

Is it possible to flip horizontally a picture which contain in canvas but not the canvas.

I have canvas with sevral images.

I want to flip only one image from all the images which inside the canvas.

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LTNT/)

I have this code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 10;
      var y = 10;
      var width = 200;
      var height = 137;
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.translate(width, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
       };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

These lines     :

```
context.translate(width, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
```

flip the image and the canvas togther.

I want to do somthing like this:

```
imageObj.translate(width, 0);
imageObj.scale(-1, 1);
```

how to to do it ?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will rotate the context when you draw the image and then restore it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 10;
      var y = 10;
      var width = 200;
      var height = 137;
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.save();
        context.translate(width, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
        context.restore();
       };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```